# How to record how long spark IO operations take?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to know if anyone knows of a way to time how long Spark takes to read and write, specifically read, from a file.

Since RDDs are lazily evaluated, is it possible to time how long one transformation takes? Reading from a file does not get executed until I perform an action on it, but I only want the timing results of the read transformation. Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Spark narrow transformations are fused and processing is interleaved it is close to impossible to measure IO time exactly in a real pipeline.

If you are interested in an estimate of the storage performance you can create a minimal reading test:

```
sc.readText(...).foreach(_ => ())
```

and writing test:

```
// Prepare and cache data
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(...)).cache
rdd.foreach(_ => ())

// Measure only this action
rdd.saveAsTextFile(...)
```

or equivalent depending on a format you're interested in.

Once you have these two you can get detailed runtime statistics from the Spark [REST API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api).